# Function pointer not working (C++)

Tags: c++, animation, events, function-pointers, sfml

```
void close() {
    //game.close();
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    game.display();
    game.attachEvent(Event::EventType::Closed, close());
    while (game.isOpen()) {
        game.render();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'void (*)()' with an rvalue of type 'void'
>      game.attachEvent(Event::EventType::Closed, close());
>
> note: passing argument to parameter here
>   void attachEvent(sf::Event::EventType, void (*)());

Why is it displaying this error? I am trying to attach an event which I can call with `function();`. As a parameter, it is declared as `void (*function)()`.
Thanks.

Comment: I guess you mean `game.attachEvent(Event::EventType::Closed, close);`

Comment: Just use function name without (), you can add `&` for readability - `&close` but that is optional in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `close()` calls the close function and passes the result which is `void`

You want to pass the function itself with:

```
game.attachEvent(Event::EventType::Closed, close);
```

(Note there are no parenthesis on `close`)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `close()` pass it using `close`, so `game.attachEvent(Event::EventType::Closed, close)`